# Sorting datatable on multiple values

Tags: html, sorting, datatable

I am a bit rusty at front end design and so I am at a bit of a loss on how to proceed.

I am using the jQueryUI DataTable plugin to create a table. There are more columns than can be easily displayed in the horizontal space available but I need them to all be visible, the PO has said he wants to "wrap the columns into another line".

I could do that by taking all of the columns and putting them into a  within a single column in the datatable. The problem is I would need to be able to have the DT plugin sort/filter based upon several values inside the div. And I don't know how to do that.

Is there a better solution? Or, something I am missing?

Go from something like this :

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>name 1</th>
    <th>rank 1</th>
    <th>serial number 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>name 2</th>
    <th>rank 2</th>
    <th>serial number 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>name 3</th>
    <th>rank 3</th>
    <th>serial number 3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To something like this :

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <div>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>name 1</th>
      <th>rank 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>serial number 1</th>
    </tr>
  </div>

   <div>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>name 2</th>
      <th>rank 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>serial number 2</th>
    </tr>

  </div>
   <div>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>name 3</th>
      <th>rank 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>serial number 3</th>
    </tr>
  </div>

</table>
```

Comment: I think you should check out the "Child rows" option https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html . You can put the extra columns info inside the expansion (after clicking on the + sign in the example they show). BTW, putting <div> tags around <tr> tags is not valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Using Child Row:

> The DataTables API has a number of methods for attaching child rows to
>   a parent row in the DataTable. This can be used to show additional
>   information about a row, useful for cases where you wish to convey
>   more information about a row than there is space for in the host table

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Updates:
Changed child row with one data without header/title. Styled with 100% width.

```
text-align: center !important;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
```

See example here:

```js
var dataSet =[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$137,500",
      "start_date": "2012/08/06",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9608"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Rhona Davidson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$327,900",
      "start_date": "2010/10/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "6200"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Colleen Hurst",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$205,500",
      "start_date": "2009/09/15",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2360"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Sonya Frost",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$103,600",
      "start_date": "2008/12/13",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "1667"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Jena Gaines",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$90,560",
      "start_date": "2008/12/19",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3814"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Quinn Flynn",
      "position": "Support Lead",
      "salary": "$342,000",
      "start_date": "2013/03/03",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "9497"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Charde Marshall",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$470,600",
      "start_date": "2008/10/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6741"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Haley Kennedy",
      "position": "Senior Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$313,500",
      "start_date": "2012/12/18",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3597"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$385,750",
      "start_date": "2010/03/17",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1965"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Michael Silva",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$198,500",
      "start_date": "2012/11/27",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1581"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Paul Byrd",
      "position": "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
      "salary": "$725,000",
      "start_date": "2010/06/09",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3059"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Gloria Little",
      "position": "Systems Administrator",
      "salary": "$237,500",
      "start_date": "2009/04/10",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1721"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Bradley Greer",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$132,000",
      "start_date": "2012/10/13",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "2558"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Dai Rios",
      "position": "Personnel Lead",
      "salary": "$217,500",
      "start_date": "2012/09/26",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "2290"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Jenette Caldwell",
      "position": "Development Lead",
      "salary": "$345,000",
      "start_date": "2011/09/03",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1937"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "Yuri Berry",
      "position": "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
      "salary": "$675,000",
      "start_date": "2009/06/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "6154"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Caesar Vance",
      "position": "Pre-Sales Support",
      "salary": "$106,450",
      "start_date": "2011/12/12",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8330"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Doris Wilder",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$85,600",
      "start_date": "2010/09/20",
      "office": "Sidney",
      "extn": "3023"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Angelica Ramos",
      "position": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "salary": "$1,200,000",
      "start_date": "2009/10/09",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "5797"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Gavin Joyce",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$92,575",
      "start_date": "2010/12/22",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8822"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Jennifer Chang",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$357,650",
      "start_date": "2010/11/14",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "9239"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Brenden Wagner",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$206,850",
      "start_date": "2011/06/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1314"
    },
    {
      "id": "29",
      "name": "Fiona Green",
      "position": "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "salary": "$850,000",
      "start_date": "2010/03/11",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2947"
    },
    {
      "id": "30",
      "name": "Shou Itou",
      "position": "Regional Marketing",
      "salary": "$163,000",
      "start_date": "2011/08/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8899"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "name": "Michelle House",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$95,400",
      "start_date": "2011/06/02",
      "office": "Sidney",
      "extn": "2769"
    },
    {
      "id": "32",
      "name": "Suki Burks",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$114,500",
      "start_date": "2009/10/22",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6832"
    },
    {
      "id": "33",
      "name": "Prescott Bartlett",
      "position": "Technical Author",
      "salary": "$145,000",
      "start_date": "2011/05/07",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3606"
    },
    {
      "id": "34",
      "name": "Gavin Cortez",
      "position": "Team Leader",
      "salary": "$235,500",
      "start_date": "2008/10/26",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2860"
    },
    {
      "id": "35",
      "name": "Martena Mccray",
      "position": "Post-Sales support",
      "salary": "$324,050",
      "start_date": "2011/03/09",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8240"
    },
    {
      "id": "36",
      "name": "Unity Butler",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$85,675",
      "start_date": "2009/12/09",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "id": "37",
      "name": "Howard Hatfield",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$164,500",
      "start_date": "2008/12/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "7031"
    },
    {
      "id": "38",
      "name": "Hope Fuentes",
      "position": "Secretary",
      "salary": "$109,850",
      "start_date": "2010/02/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6318"
    },
    {
      "id": "39",
      "name": "Vivian Harrell",
      "position": "Financial Controller",
      "salary": "$452,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9422"
    },
    {
      "id": "40",
      "name": "Timothy Mooney",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$136,200",
      "start_date": "2008/12/11",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "7580"
    },
    {
      "id": "41",
      "name": "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "position": "Director",
      "salary": "$645,750",
      "start_date": "2008/09/26",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1042"
    },
    {
      "id": "42",
      "name": "Olivia Liang",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$234,500",
      "start_date": "2011/02/03",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "2120"
    },
    {
      "id": "43",
      "name": "Bruno Nash",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$163,500",
      "start_date": "2011/05/03",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6222"
    },
    {
      "id": "44",
      "name": "Sakura Yamamoto",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$139,575",
      "start_date": "2009/08/19",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "9383"
    },
    {
      "id": "45",
      "name": "Thor Walton",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$98,540",
      "start_date": "2013/08/11",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8327"
    },
    {
      "id": "46",
      "name": "Finn Camacho",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$87,500",
      "start_date": "2009/07/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2927"
    },
    {
      "id": "47",
      "name": "Serge Baldwin",
      "position": "Data Coordinator",
      "salary": "$138,575",
      "start_date": "2012/04/09",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "8352"
    },
    {
      "id": "48",
      "name": "Zenaida Frank",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$125,250",
      "start_date": "2010/01/04",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "7439"
    },
    {
      "id": "49",
      "name": "Zorita Serrano",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$115,000",
      "start_date": "2012/06/01",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "4389"
    },
    {
      "id": "50",
      "name": "Jennifer Acosta",
      "position": "Junior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$75,650",
      "start_date": "2013/02/01",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "3431"
    },
    {
      "id": "51",
      "name": "Cara Stevens",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$145,600",
      "start_date": "2011/12/06",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3990"
    },
    {
      "id": "52",
      "name": "Hermione Butler",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$356,250",
      "start_date": "2011/03/21",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1016"
    },
    {
      "id": "53",
      "name": "Lael Greer",
      "position": "Systems Administrator",
      "salary": "$103,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/27",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6733"
    },
    {
      "id": "54",
      "name": "Jonas Alexander",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$86,500",
      "start_date": "2010/07/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "8196"
    },
    {
      "id": "55",
      "name": "Shad Decker",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2008/11/13",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6373"
    },
    {
      "id": "56",
      "name": "Michael Bruce",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2011/06/27",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "id": "57",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ];
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table class="text-center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width=100%">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
 background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
 background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.text-center
{
   text-align: center !important;
   width: auto;
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have seen this example on the DataTable site. But unfortunately it is not what I have been asked to do. The PO wants a second row of data, under the first, without a title for the cell, just the data.

They also want some of the second row sells to span columns

Comment: @TerryH updated my example demo. I changed child row to consist data only and little css update to make it center.